# is any basis orthogonal for constant polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra

For set to be orthogonal, inner product of every pair would be zero.

But, there is only one basis for constant polynomials. does that mean that any basis could be orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, but over $\Bbb R$ only two are orthonormal

Answer (score 0):

The set of all constant polynomials is a one-dimensional vector space, so any basis of it would consist of a single vector (which must be a constant nonzero polynomial).  Perforce any singleton set is orthogonal.

Comment: in that sense, inner product of orthogonal basis for constant polynomials can not be defined? since there is only one basis, and nothing to be inner product with

Comment: This is incorrect.  An inner product can be defined just fine. "orthogonal" refers to inner product between two different elements; if a set has only one element there aren't two different elements to take the inner product of.